# Need to access/send var data from JavaScript to Java Spring Boot Controller ThymeLeaf

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

I'm still learning JS, Thymeleaf, and Spring Boot and can't seem to figure out how I can use data variables in my JavaScript file and send them to a database through Spring MVC controller. Here is what I have so far:

html:

```
<body>

<!--PRINT OUT TEST_VAR HERE FOR USERS TO SEE DATA-->

<script src="../static/js/TEST.js" type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/TEST.js}"></script>

</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var TEST_VAR = 37;
```

Java/Spring MVC Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "TEST_VAR", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String messages(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("test_db", "test_var");
        return "TESTindex";
// Not sure what to write in the controller.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in a SpringBoot Controller, the "value" in the requestmap annotation is where the end point is binded to

so the example below binds to  "abc.com/api/v1/17"
and 17 is the variable that will be readed from path (because if you use GET method, you need to read data from path) Get methods doesn't have request body (investigate GET and POST method diffrences, if you need )

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/{id}", method = GET)
public String getFoosBySimplePathWithPathVariable(
  @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return "you send id = " + id;
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain how this works with the sample code I provided? I think I understand correctly that I will have to pull data from the path so would that look something like: @RequestMapping(value = "/js/TEST.js/{TEST_VAR}", method = GET)

Comment: you can check this out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf

Comment: I've actually already done this program for another one of my projects, but I'm still not sure how to use vars from a javascript file and use it in a controller